# How can I get textures and baking working if I want this model to look right for exporting?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, workflow

I am currently working on a set of prop weapons for transfer to an alternant 3d software. Currently, the best I can get is materials on the meshes, but obviously I need textures so that the items actually have color to them in the other program.

I have some high-resolution PBR type material/textures to make the materials on a prop of mine more realistic but because they consist of multiple maps (displacement, normal, color, roughness etc.) I cannot figure out how to effectively use the maps on my items in uv image mode, I do have the whole item joined together, and have different materials for each piece, the issue is that the material/texture images I'm using come out as solid white or black, instead of the color, and I dont really know how to have multiple maps assigned to the same portion of the mesh except through the use of texture nodes on the material panel in node editor (I dont know if adding image nodes to material nodes is the only way textureing actually work in cycles but it seems to be as I stated before putting them in the uv image editor makes them solid white or black)

I have been planning to do baking to the materials but as I cannot figure out how to bake everything without the light effects (so that lighting has no effect on the outcome as lighting seems to be a bit finicky, and one of the items produces light on its edge so it would mess up the bake) but still includes everything else (normal maps, color, roughness etc) without me spending all year doing individual bakes on my older pc which likely wouldn't work correctly anyway.

[image: textured view of my prop]

[image: Shift+z view of my prop]

In the images above, the first is what i'm currently seeing in textured mode, not sure why the top of the blade is blue, but you can also see that in the uv image editor where that should be a metal color it is instead completely white. 
  the second image is what the prop should look like, and it has the some images textures added to the principled shader in some places to give the different materials more accuracy, but where the arrow is pointing is an emission area (energy blade) which is part of the reason I cannot bake everything as the emission would likely mess up the bake so I need a way to do both things if possible, have textures uv mapped to my models (there are multiple of different looks) and baked versions which can include everything but not be messed up by lighting.

I feel as though I've explained the situation clearly enough. It shouldn't cause much confusion, but my train of thought is usually different top others so I can elaborate if needed.

Comment: i have been attempting to bake the materials to the mesh (when it is joined together) but every time i try to bake a texture as shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU&index=3&list=LLxAu6QG5BUG6sn4MwI-P0TQ&t=197s

it instead bakes the textures to the wrong thing entirely for some reason.

Comment: So far i'm still getting nowhere with my baking, every time i try to bake the individual parts, it for some reason switches the selected texture, and screws up the one i'm attempting to bake, so i don't have much of an idea why it keeps doing this.

for proper clarification when i say it screws up the texture, what is happening is that the metal texture for the blade (see images of original post) keeps getting switched with the texture of the cloth wrapped on the handle which either messes up the metal, or the cloth, but i'm not even selecting cloth in the first place.